# Hadoop web Page," SlaveNodeName:50060/tasktracker.jsp" is unreachable

Tags: hadoop

Recently I have configure a hadoop platform with three computer:one is for namenode/jobtracker. The other two is for tasktracker, the computer name is gp and ls-ubuntu. But the question is when I want to search the gp Node from web Page, I am rejected. What happened?

On gp Node, the /etc/hosts is as follows:
192.168.0.102   gp      # Added by NetworkManager

127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost

::1     gp      localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

192.168.0.89    node1

192.168.0.77    node2

192.168.0.102   node3

127.0.1.1       gp

node1 is my jobtracker, node2 and node3 is tasktrackers.

the url of gp is unreachable:   http://gp:50075/browseDirectory.jsp--------------wrong
when I modify the gp to node3, it seems right. But I can't go to the datanode page only by click the link。

I have use ssh to connect all the nodes.

What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove that 127.0.1.1 gp and make it 127.0.0.1 and make your host entries as follows and try:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost gp

::1 gp localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

192.168.0.89 node1

192.168.0.77 node2

192.168.0.102 node3
```

it will work. as 127.0.1.1 always create problem, i dont know the reason otherwise i would have told you :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have got the right result as your suggestion~-~